# Получение ответа от Web-App из Inline-кнопки

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram-3.x

Создаю телеграм бота на aiogram 3.х, не могу понять как получить ответ из WebApp, важно, то что WebApp должен быть вызван через inline-button.
В документации не смог разобраться.

Дополнение:
Использую язык **Python** и библиотеку **aiogram 3**
Вот код самой инлайн кнопки:
`kb.button(text="  Меню", web_app=WebAppInfo(url="https://neko-kitchen.ru"))`
При нажатии на кнопку открывается Web-app(сайт), в нём имеется форма.
Так вот вопрос в том, как мне получать данные с этой формы обратно в **телеграм**.

[Вот ссылка на официальную документацию](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.